# Show blocks only in index page by only using layout

Tags: layout, blocks

I have two blocks

```
<block type="core/template" name="homepage" as="homepage" template="page/html/homepage.phtml" />

<block type="raymanproductstab/productstab" name="productstab" as="productstab" template="productstab/productstab.phtml" />
```

How can I show these two block only in index page only by modifying layout (but not using backend cms)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 2 options.
Option 1.
Edit the homepage from `CMS->Pages` and add your this in the layout update field

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="homepage" as="homepage" template="page/html/homepage.phtml" />

    <block type="raymanproductstab/productstab" name="productstab" as="productstab" template="productstab/productstab.phtml" />
</reference>
```

or add this in the content of the page.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/homepage.phtml"}}
{{block type="raymanproductstab/productstab" template="productstab/productstab.phtml"}}
```

Option 2. Via layout files.

Add this in one of your layout files:

```
<cms_index_index><!-- layout handle for the homepage -->
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="homepage" as="homepage" template="page/html/homepage.phtml" />
        <block type="raymanproductstab/productstab" name="productstab" as="productstab" template="productstab/productstab.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```